# Tutorials and other supporting resources for Schematron

Tags: xml, visual-studio, xsd, schematron

I am interested in learning Schematron. Please suggest a tutorial I can use to practice. I am expecting a complete tutorial that I can use to develop my skills well. I already know the basics of DTD, XSD and XSLT.

I have tried using the [Zvon tutorials](http://www.zvon.org/xxl/SchematronTutorial/General/contents.html) and [Schematron.com](http://www.schematron.com).

Also, I have been struggling to find the a Schematron editor for practicing. If it is Visual Studio then I would feel heavenly. Is it possible to implement Schematron the way we implement XSD and XSLT docs? Is it equally easy?

Comment: Wouldn't it be nice if working through a tutorial could turn a novice into a professional -- in any discipline.

Comment: seems like no one is interested in my question ..  100 bounty going to get ruined .. :-| am sad ..

Comment: Oh, I'm interested. I just don't have an answer for you. Most of us who do schematron learned it the hands on way - as a new tool in our set of validation techniques. Schematron is fairly trivial as validation technologies go. If you can already do XSD and XSLT what more do you need?

Comment: hmm .. well said. Schematron isn't XSD but it works where XSD stops working and where XSLT isn't required .. Just because of my self interest/curiosity I asked this question .. ya you right, I don't need schematron anymore as it doesn't have much supporting environment. ;) thanx for the comments .. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Tutorials:

- http://www.dpawson.co.uk/schematron/index.html
- http://www.xfront.com/schematron/index.html
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/schematron_started.aspx
- http://www.docstoc.com/docs/2134799/Schematron-Editor-Tutorial

Editors:

- http://www.xmlblueprint.com/schematron-editor.htm ($80)
- http://sourceforge.net/projects/cs-wizard/ (open source)

Misc:

- http://sourceforge.net/projects/schematron-net/

Comment: Not a problem. I hope they are helpful.